# Pulling ca.org1.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-ca:-1.0.4)... ERROR: invalid tag format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i tried hyperledger compose online playground and now want to use it locally.
but facing below error after all images are successfully pulled and tries to start.

```
"WARNING: The ARCH variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Pulling ca.org1.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-ca:-1.0.4)...
ERROR: invalid tag format"
```

I am using 
Ubuntu 14.04, 
docker 17.03.0-ce and docker-compose,
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1

Answer (score 0):

From the docker website on [tags](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#parent-command):

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name **may not start with a period or a dash** and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

Edit: However, the problem in your case is likely the previous message that an environment variable is not set. The command you are running is likely trying to pull `hyperledger/fabric-ca:${ARCH}-1.0.4` but `ARCH` is replaced by an empty string.

Comment: actually i am not pulling images manually, but following hyperledger compose tutorial. 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html
I get error after executing below command
"curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash"

Comment: What's the output you get for `docker images | grep hyperledger/fabric-ca`?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony, Yes i login as non root user, but  i use sudo for this command "sudo curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash"

Comment: @TillHoffmann, Here is the output  

```hyperledger/fabric-ca        x86_64-1.0.4        8e691b3509bf        2 months ago        238 MB```

Comment: @TillHoffmann
As you said it is not picking ARCH variable in "composer-data/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/startFabric.sh"  

```#Detect architecture
ARCH=`uname -m`

ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml down
ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml up -d```  
I tried setting it in environment variable permanently, tried to hard code inside code but every time fresh copy of files gets downloaded. So no success

Comment: yes, correct use `curl -sSL http://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash` - it will `a)` Download Fabric v1.0 + Composer Playground `b)` Start Fabric v1.0 `c)`   Create and join a channel and `d)`  Start Composer Playground which is configured to talk to the installed/ running Fabric v1.0. What is the output of `uname -m` ?
    Open a browser pointing to Composer Playground

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony ```output: x86_64```

Comment: Well i installed it through npm. I followed this link "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools" 
and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar kind of issue raised in "https://github.com/IBM/hyperledger-fabric-on-linux-one/issues/15" and one of the suggested approach is to completely clean the image removing all docker images all install scripts and start again.

However i followed this link (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools)
and now everything is up and running

Comment: glad to hear. Seems the cleanup cleardown/teardown has resolved it then.